# FFMPEG: Combine "Create video from images" + scale to x + add audio + overlay logo

Tags: ffmpeg

I´m working on a webcam-project. It is for generating timelapse videos of sunset/sundown.

I´m using a raspberrypi to generate them with gphoto2 + DSLR.

At the end of the day the images should get to an video, with audio and an overlay logo.
And it should be scaled to 1920 pixel.
I got a nice solution an it worked.

1. Producing the timelapse video an scale it:

   `ffmpeg -y -framerate 25 -start_number 0000001 -i /var/www/html/webcam/2020-01-05_bilder/%7d.jpg -vf scale=1920:-1 -pix_fmt yuv420p /var/www/html/webcam/2020-01-05-tag-output-1920.mp4`

2. Taking the output of (1) and add an overlay-logo, add audio

   `ffmpeg -y -i '/var/www/html/webcam/2020-01-05-tag-output-1920.mp4' 
   -i '/var/www/html/webcam-scripts/graphics/logo.png' 
   -i '/var/www/html/webcam-scripts/sounds/chill_time_5.mp3' 
   -shortest -filter_complex '[1][0]scale2ref=h=ow/mdar:w=iw/6[#A logo][liebfrauen]; [#A logo]format=argb,colorchannelmixer=aa=0.95[#B logo transparent]; [liebfrauen][#B logo transparent] overlay=(main_w-w)-(main_w*0.05):(main_h-h)-(main_h*0.01)' 
   -c:v libx264 -crf 18 -preset slow -pix_fmt yuv420p -c:a aac -strict -2 
   '/var/www/html/webcam/2020-01-05-tag-1920.mp4`

I tried to combine both actions, but I get an error:

```
ffmpeg -y -framerate 25 -start_number 0000001 -i '/var/www/html/webcam/2020-01-05_bilder/%7d.jpg' -vf scale=1920:-1 -pix_fmt yuv420p -i '/var/www/html/webcam-scripts/graphics/logo.png' -i '/var/www/html/webcam-scripts/sounds/chill_time_5.mp3' -shortest -filter_complex '[1][0]scale2ref=h=ow/mdar:w=iw/6[#A logo][liebfrauen]; [#A logo]format=argb,colorchannelmixer=aa=0.95[#B logo transparent]; [liebfrauen][#B logo transparent] overlay=(main_w-w)-(main_w*0.05):(main_h-h)-(main_h*0.01)' -c:v libx264 -crf 18 -preset slow -pix_fmt yuv420p -c:a aac -strict -2 '/var/www/html/webcam/2020-01-05-tag-1920.mp4'
```

Error: Filtergraph 'scale=720:-1' was specified through the -vf/-af/-filter option for output stream 0:0, which is fed from a complex filtergraph.
-vf/-af/-filter and -filter_complex cannot be used together for the same stream.

Isn`t it possible to combine these inputs and scale it? Or ... Where is my misunderstanding?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't mix `-vf` and `-filter_complex`. Do all filtering in one [filtergraph](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#Filtergraph-description).

```
ffmpeg -y -framerate 25 -i '/var/www/html/webcam/2020-01-05_bilder/%7d.jpg' -i '/var/www/html/webcam-scripts/graphics/logo.png' -i '/var/www/html/webcam-scripts/sounds/chill_time_5.mp3' -filter_complex '[0]scale=1920:-2[v0];[1][v0]scale2ref=h=ow/mdar:w=iw/6[#A logo][liebfrauen]; [#A logo]format=argb,colorchannelmixer=aa=0.95[#B logo transparent]; [liebfrauen][#B logo transparent] overlay=(main_w-w)-(main_w*0.05):(main_h-h)-(main_h*0.01),format=yuv420p' -c:v libx264 -crf 18 -preset slow -c:a aac -shortest '/var/www/html/webcam/2020-01-05-tag-1920.mp4'
```

- No need for `-strict -2`. It does nothing for modern `ffmpeg`.
- I replaced `-pix_fmt yuv420p` with `format=yuv420p` so it is more organized.
- `-start_number 0000001` is not needed because `1` is the default.

Comment: Thanks Ilogan! Now I understand my mistake! It works very well! Great. Thanks for your help and to save cpu-time on my raspi an co2.